# In PyDev, how can I get autocompletion for an instance returned by a method?

Tags: python, pydev

When I use a method of `Class-A` to return an instance of `Class-B`, PyDev will not offer me auto-completion for the instance of `Class-B`. Is there a way to make this work so I don't potentially mistype a method name or forget an argument? Otherwise, PyDev loses much of its value!

Comment: I think you can use `assert isinstance(returnedinstance, ClassB)`, but I can't test it right this second.

Comment: @g.d.d.c That works! Could you please state this as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the whole scope of a class, i.e. to tell a class that one of its variables is always an instance of some other class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wonder if you're using some combination of classes / containers that hinders pydev's ability to predict your return value's type.  This super-simplistic example works on my system and I get full code completion on `inst`:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, params = None):
    self.myBs = [B() for _ in range(10)]

  def getB(self):
    return self.myBs[5]

class B(object):
  def foo(self):
    pass

inst = A().getB()
# Auto-complete broken.  PyDev thinks inst is a list.
assert isinstance(inst, B)
# Auto-complete working again.
```

After additional detail, the `assert` statement is necessary to trigger PyDev's autocomplete functionality.

Comment: I think what confuses PyDev is storing an instance into a dictionary and pulling it back out again. The dictionary implementation is hidden behind other methods in `Class-A`.

Comment: Ahh, yes.  A list or dictionary of instances makes things different.  Let me test a bit.

Comment: @JimL. - I think adding the assert statement is the key in that case.  Again, pretty simplistic example, but on my machine I get odd auto-completes before the assert statement, but the expected suggestions after the assert.

Comment: It does indeed work! Could you please state that as an answer so I can accept it as the best?

Answer (score 2):

Asserting isInstance breaks the "Better to ask forgiveness than permission" paradigm in python.

Pydev understands specific decorators in docstrings for type hinting.

Here's a set of examples: http://pydev.sourceforge.net/manual_adv_type_hints.html

```
class Foo(object):
    def method(self):
        pass

    def otherMethod(self):
        pass

def returnFoo():
    return Foo()

"""@type fooInstance: Foo"""
fooInstance = returnFoo()
```

I haven't had much luck with the return type (using the epydoc syntax) but haven't tried much, but whatever the object is assigned to can be declared by the type you are expecting as in the example above.

Comment: There is a similar link (not sure if newer or older) here: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sphinx doc comments:

```
def get_date(...):
    """:rtype date"""
    ...
    return date
```

For more see: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html

Comment: Amusing that visiting that site says, "Your connection is not secure

The owner of www.pydev.org has configured their website improperly. To protect your information from being stolen, Firefox has not connected to this website."

Comment: Yeah just remove the 's' character from `https://`, I removed it as it is not required.